# Need csv format for size and color Configurable product Magento2?

Tags: magento2, import-products, product-import

Please Anyone suggest the sample csv file for both color and size Product for bulk import in magento2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below magento 2 official document to import configurable product.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-transfer-configurable-products.html

Sample CSV file download from below link

http://www.sharecsv.com/s/f752e479dc0cbe834c9187c485c1d27b/catalog_product_configurable_import.csv

Answer (score 1):

First Solution : Please go through this csv format for size and color Configurable product Magento2.Set size,color variation as attached image

[image]

Second Solution Go through that link and read this blog

```
https://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2016/01/magento-2-import-configurable-products/
```

Edit: You have to also add variation size and color in column `additional_attributes` like `color=Orange`.

Comment: It has only color.How can we give size attribute? I have a product with both Color and size.

Comment: You can use color and size variation like this sku=CP!-magento,color=Orange|sku=CP!-greeen,size=medium in "configurable_variations" column. Thanks.